# How to display my Linearlayout with Imageview inside it around scrollview?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview

I have a problem, to show my image in android. 
For this, you can see below the output of my emulator. 
[image]

I have a `ScrollView` with 2 childrean. 
One is the `TextView`, and the other one is the `ImageView`. 
When I scroll down, I can only see the text of the `TextView`.

But **not** the image of the `Imageview`.

Here is a part of my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ScrollView
            android:layout_marginLeft="260dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_handlungsleitfaden_strassenfuehrer"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/bild_handlungsleitfaden_strassenfuehrer"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/maschine"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/handlungsleitfaden_btn"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="7dp"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:text="weiter" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Does anybody have an idea how to fix it? :) 
Thank you

Comment: Could you give the whole layout please? We could then optimise the whole layout, as I already see you have made many mistakes.

Comment: Thanks, it would be very good. Is there a way to send you the layout? Because this would be like another question..

Comment: Yeah sure, you could just ask another question on stackoverflow for people to optimise your layout and send the link in the comments here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just provide orientation to `linearLayout`, By default orientation is horizontal so you have to provide `android:orientation="vertical"` like this :

```
    <ScrollView
           android:layout_marginLeft="260dp"
           android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
           android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_handlungsleitfaden_strassenfuehrer"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/bild_handlungsleitfaden_strassenfuehrer"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/maschine"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </ScrollView>


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/handlungsleitfaden_btn"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="7dp"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:text="weiter" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is , You didn't **`set orientation`** for the linearlayout.

```
<LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

Try adding,

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

Comment: Thank you a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

You are forgetting to give orientation to linear layout.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
```

Comment: Thank you a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you forgot this line
 **`android:orientation="vertical"`**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
```

Comment: Thank you a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_handlungsleitfaden_strassenfuehrer"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Nilesgh Eayjdfp"
                android:scrollbars="vertical" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/bild_handlungsleitfaden_strassenfuehrer"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/abc" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/handlungsleitfaden_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_margin="7dp"
        android:text="weiter"
        android:textAllCaps="false" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot :)

Comment: @JosipaAllen happy to help u

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will work for you

Add below line to LinearLayout

```
  android:orientation="vertical"
```

And add below line to ScrollView

```
 android:fillViewport="true"
```

Comment: Thank you a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Give orientation in Linear layout

```
android:orientation = "vertical"
```